# Passing face to function non-interactively

Tags: faces

With the following function executed non-interactively, would it be sensible to pass the face name or a string?

```
(defun laxy-descface (facenm)
  "Describe the typeface properties of face name FACENM."
 
  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("mode-line" "mode-line-inactive" "text-property")) )
      (completing-read "Face_property: " cseq nil t "text-property"))))

  (pcase facenm
    ("text-property"
        (describe-face (get-text-property (point) 'face)))
    ("mode-line"
        (describe-face (intern facenm)))
    ("mode-line-inactive"
        (describe-face (intern facenm)))))
```

Comment: It would make more sense to pass it as an atom, like all face-related functions Emacs provides do. If you happen to have the face name as a string, you can always call your function using `(laxy-describe (intern my-face-name))`.

Comment: I would have to distinguish between interactive and non-interactive use.

Comment: A side note: Remember that the `face` text property can contain a lot more than simply a face name. It can contain list of face names as well as (if I remember correctly) raw plist entries like `:foreground "blue"`, which I doubt `describe-face` will handle.

Comment: Why would you have to distinguish between interactive and non-interactive use?

Comment: Because I am using `completing-read` during interactive execution which returns a string.  That's how I fill `facenm`, which one need to convert appropriately.

Comment: Why don't you move the `intern` into the `interactive` clause? I've always found it more intuitive to design functions primarily as lisp functions, and make the interactive clause adapt to that.

Comment: Cannot use intern for `text-property`.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use atoms in this case?

Comment: An atom is what `intern` returns, or what you get if you write `'mode-line`. What I suggested is that the parameter `facenm` should be an atom (`mode-line`) rather than a string (`"mode-line"`).

Comment: You can pass in some other value instead of `"text-property"`, maybe nil?